# Default PCM-format on Android

Tags: android, audio, default

Does anyone know, if this is the default PCM-format on the most Android (ARM) devices?

```
2 channels
16 bit
Little Endian
```

The underlying "tinyalsa" can handle

```
SNDRV_PCM_FORMAT_S32_LE
SNDRV_PCM_FORMAT_S8
SNDRV_PCM_FORMAT_S24_LE
SNDRV_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE
```

but I cannot think of that Android uses different configurations (?).

Little Endian is sure on ARM-devices.

And what about the 2 channels? I found no way to get mono-audio played, so I think it's always converted into 2 channels.

Are there devices with multichannel-support?

I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I'd say 16 bit little endian, yes. The number of channels depend on what the application requests. Though some devices will run some / all output threads in a stereo configuration, similar to what you found in your tests. Typically this will be mixed back to mono by the analogue codec or DSP if you're outputting to a mono sink (e.g. many devices only have a single loudspeaker).

> The underlying "tinyalsa" can handle

Many devices don't use libtinyalsa. They have their own user-space interface towards the kernel space ALSA drivers. For example, recent Qualcomm platforms uses their own libalsa-intf for most playback, while libtinyalsa is used only for USB audio playback (and possibly A2DP).

As far as multichannel support goes, it would be down-mixed to stereo if written to a mono/stereo sink (i.e. on the internal loudspeaker or a 3.5mm headset), possibly with the help of a virtualizer effect that creates a fake sense of surround. True surround sound would be limited to sinks that support it, i.e. HDMI/MHL, and possibly USB. It should be noted that some devices down-mix to stereo even in the HDMI/MHL case.

Comment: Oh, that's already a good answer, thank you. By the way, do you know how many (never) Android mobile-devices use tinyalsa meanwhile, approximately? ;)

Comment: Qualcomm, whose solution I briefly mentioned, is the biggest vendor on the market. ST-Ericsson uses a similar approach when it comes to tinyalsa (IIRC). I don't know what Samsung/NVidia/Intel does.

Comment: Because I've got a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and it uses tinyalsa, I think Samsung goes the tinyalsa-way :)